# Calling jar from PHP

Tags: java, php, permissions, jar

I've got a jar file I created that can generate a PDF file. I've called it from the command line like this -

```
java -jar project.jar 'Author, An---A Title'
```

This works fine but when I call the same jar file from a PHP file with the following code it creates a file with the correct name but its empty and has zero bytes.

```
<?php
    echo exec("java -jar project.jar 'Author, An---A Title'");
?>
```

I'm sure this is a problem not with the jar (since it works from the commandline) and I'm almost sure its not from the PHP file (since it created the empty file, so it must have been read), so I think the problem might be with permissions on the directory? I'm using linux and the PHP is running through XAMMP which is in the OPT directory. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this your own JAR or a 3rd party one? Which one? Do you understand Java?

Comment: I have done this a lot of times, that should work as expected. Maybe it is a user/right problem. Have you called the commandline with the same user that is used by your webserver/php process?

Comment: If you can "su" to the user which Apache runs as you can test your permissions theory. `su apache;java -jar ..etc..`  Might not work though, the Apache user often doesn't have a shell.  Might need some detective work to find out the user your Apache runs as, try `ps aux | grep apache` or `ps aux | grep httpd`.  The user should be the first column of the `ps` output

Comment: Hi Robin, I changed the user for the whole Apache directory and I still can't get it to work, this is the strangest thing. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have control over the Java source code but at least the symptoms indicate that it is not calling `close()` on the `OutputStream` or `Writer` of the file in question.

---

**Update**: try [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead to see what the result says. Probably it threw some exception halfway which got written to the `stderr` which you completely missed 
in the PHP code. The [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) namely only captures the `stdout`.

```
$result = shell_exec("java -jar project.jar 'Author, An---A Title'");
if ($result) {
    echo nl2br($result);
} else {
    echo "shell_exec() failed";
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have worked. I don't think its a coding problem since I don't have a problem when calling it from the commandline.

Comment: See answer update. Probably you can find more interesting information in the stderr.

Comment: Hi, I just tried you update code with no luck. Now I'm sure its something to do with permissions. I tried manually creating a text file, which works. Then when I try to save something I can't. I can save after I chmod 777 everything in the directory. I have to do this after each file I manually create. How can I make sure all files in a specific directory are always writeable? Thanks.